# Improve differentiation between relationships and dating tags

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the difference between these two tags: [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) and [dating](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dating)

Right now, only [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) has a description:

> This refers to relationships between a child or group of children and
>   other children, their siblings, or their parents. This could also
>   refer to a relationship between parents in regards to the rearing of a
>   child.

Key points to consider:

- what sort of questions would each one encompass
- what should the tag descriptions be
- is one for platonic relationships and the other for romantic
- is [dating](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dating) a specific subset of [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships), or are they more independent

Answer (score 1):

[relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) shouldn't particularly specify dating, in my opinion; it should be more general in terms of 'person to person relationships', including child to child, boyfriend to girlfriend, parent to child, parent to grandparent, etc.  It includes boyfriend-girlfriend (dating), when the question is about the relationship factor.

I think it's okay that [dating](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dating) is partially a subset of this. Dating questions can sometimes overlap with relationships, and sometimes not:

> What is appropriate to give as a gift for a first year dating anniversary?

(while not a great question here) would be fine for [dating](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dating) but not really [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships), while [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) would also fit on

> My son is having a hard time understanding how to act with his longtime platonic friend who he is now dating.

I would suggest as a tag description for dating something like:

> Questions about (older) children's romantic relationships.

Keep it simple.  If it ends up nearly always having [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) on it, I don't think that's a big deal.

For relationships I think how it currently stands is okay, but we could add:

> This refers to relationships between a child or group of children and other children, their siblings, or their parents. This could also refer to a relationship between parents in regards to the rearing of a child.  See also [dating](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dating) for romantic relationships.

Not suggesting [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships) is specifically wrong, as often the relationship aspect can be partially independent of the fact that it's a romantic relationship, but suggesting it as another tag.

Answer (score 0):

Dating as a tag, to me, would mean the question is specifically about the dating process:

- What are appropriate date activities for my child?
- When should my child start dating?
- How do I teach my child to make smart choices about dating?
- Is it normal for x-year-olds to say they're "dating"?

(Note to self: Why aren't the first 3 questions already?!)

So maybe:

> This refers to the act of dating, or courtship. Questions are about the dating or courtship processes themselves rather than about relationships. See [relationships](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relationships).

I would personally change the relationships tag to be a little more broad, since that's how it's used anyway:

> This refers to relationships of parents or children with immediate family, extended family, or friends. Questions can be about establishing, maintaining, or improving relationships.

This new definition would include questions that involve relationships with aunts, uncles, cousins, grandparents, friends of parents or children, etc.